# Merge a curve with an object

Tags: bezier-curves

How can i merge a curve with an other mesh? It doesn't work with  ctrl+j - Error: no mesh data to join.

Is possible to do that?

I created a lightbulb and the filament is made from a curve and i want to merge it with the other parts.

Comment: You cannot have objects that use different kinds of data.
Mesh objects, and curves cannot be combined.
But why do you need to merge them to be part of the same object? Just parent it.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed there is no *mesh*-data if your object is a curve.
If you just want to move them together parenting the filament to the bulb would be a great non destructive option. Otherwise if you don't need to modify your filament anymore you can convert the curve to a mesh `Object` > `Convert to` > `Mesh from curve` and after that join the two meshes with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>